# Why does chromecast need internet?

Tags: streaming, chromecast

A major limitation of the Chromecast is that it wants an internet connection to work. Without that it refuses to stream local media on local networks which can cause a lot of trouble to people for example [at hotels](https://www.google.de/search?q=chromecast+hotel) or [giving a presentation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25720919/2235831).

So I am wondering for what purpose this major limitation was build in, if it could be easily avoided by handing Chromecast resolved URLs.

Answer (score 0):

For me it's not a limitation but an advantage. Chromecast's best part is that it streams directly from you WiFi. It won't consume your mobile's battery, and will be super smooth without lags. This is the purpose of the streamer. Only the commands (cast, pause, etc) are sent through your mobile / desktop / tablet.

This being said, you can circumvent the internet's requirement by creating a mobile hotspot, to stream some offline media. Take a look at [LocalCast](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.stefanpledl.localcast&hl=en).

Comment: The point is you can't connect to Chromecast without it having an internet connection and LocalCast cannot change this.

Answer (score 0):

For one, Chromecast is not an always-powered device; it doesn't have batteries inside so it cannot keep time, hence it needs internet to have an accurate time in order for many things to work properly, such as authentication handshake, etc. There are other reasons on top of that as well but that alone should give you a reason as to why it is the way it is.

Comment: This only explains why it needs internet to boot, which could be acceptable.

Comment: You need to avoid any drift as well, so a one-time sync is not adequate.

Comment: What are you talking about? A Rasperry Pi has no batteries either but plays great offline without any drifts. However a not perfect playback is still better than none.

Comment: Does RP support the level of security that Chromecast does??? Does RP even care if time is not sync'ed? Chromecast enables various providers to play encrypted media through various security models that it has; it is a trusted device and as such, it requires an accurate time, not just at the boot time but for extended period of time.

Comment: We cannot debate about Chromecast's security because its a black box but I don't see why it should become too vulnerable to run after a few hours without time sync. Some references would be helpful to support such speculations. The RP doesn't need this for its security and just does what the user tells it to do.

Answer (score 0):

This [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/1kq3o2/why_does_chromecast_need_internet/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) gives some answers.